# Moveit installation in Ubuntu, error "Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed" occurred

Tags: ubuntu, ros, moveit

When I installed **moveit** on Ubuntu 14.4, an error occurred, after command line "catkin_make".

error details are as following:

```
`heng@AspireE1:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
 Base path: /home/heng/catkin_ws
 Source space: /home/heng/catkin_ws/src
 Build space: /home/heng/catkin_ws/build
 Devel space: /home/heng/catkin_ws/devel
 Install space: /home/heng/catkin_ws/install
  ####
 #### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home     /heng/catkin_ws/build"
 ####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/heng/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target  _kinova_msgs_generate_messages_check_deps_ArmPoseActionResult
[  0%] Built target   
[ 43%] Built target moveit_robot_state
[ 44%] Built target moveit_robot_trajectory
[ 44%] [ 44%] Built target moveit_dynamics_solver
Built target moveit_kinematics_metrics
[ 44%] Built target moveit_trajectory_processing
[ 45%] [ 45%] Built target moveit_planning_interface
Building CXX object moveit_core/collision_detection/CMakeFiles/moveit_collision_detection.dir/src/collision_octomap_filter.cpp.o
/home/heng/catkin_ws/src/moveit_core/collision_detection  /src/collision_octomap_filter.cpp: In function ‘int   collision_detection::refineContactNormals(const ObjectConstPtr&,  collision_detection::CollisionResult&, double, double, bool, double, double)’:
 /home/heng/catkin_ws/src/moveit_core/collision_detection /src/collision_octomap_filter.cpp:119:71: error: conversion from ‘const  boost::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>’ to non-scalar type  ‘std::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree>’ requested std::shared_ptr<const octomap::OcTree> octree = shape_octree->octree;
                                                                   ^
make[2]: *** [moveit_core/collision_detection/CMakeFiles /moveit_collision_detection.dir/src/collision_octomap_filter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [moveit_core/collision_detection/CMakeFiles /moveit_collision_detection.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed

error occur in [45%],error is "Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed"
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try installing it :

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-moveit-full
```

the link is from [here](http://moveit.ros.org/install/) and it worked for me on ROS Indigo  / Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: thank you ,my classmates have helped me solve this problem.But i still do not know how to solve it.